# NSString to NSDate doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

now it works with this code:

```
NSString *myDate = @"06/18/2015 8:26:17 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM. HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
cell.timeLabel.text = dateString;
```

Comment: Besides the date format being completely wrong, there is no need to `alloc/init` the `NSDate` object.

Comment: As you use this date in the UI, I suggest you to use one of Apple's predifined date style as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html). It handle all different user's locales for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the date format as the string

```
NSString *myDate = @"06/18/2015 8:26:17 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];
//Set New Date Format as you want
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM. HH:mm"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: This is not right. The day and month are backwards and it's not a 2-digit hour.

Comment: Also, the OP appears to want to change the date's format so the answer should show how to use two different date formats to get the desired result.

Comment: I still think you need `h` and not `hh` for the original format string since the date string doesn't have a 2-digit hour.

Comment: @DoHi7 you have done alloc init. directly use `[dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];` working here

Comment: @rmaddy I have seen. but out put also came with hh !!

Comment: You also need to set the date formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX`. Otherwise you will have problems due to device time settings such as the 12/24 hour setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong in your code Dohi7 because i tested it and the date is displayed correctly with @"dd.MM. HH:mm" and @"dd.MM. H:mm" both format. Please check the value of dateFromString again by printing in the console.

And yeah Ashish is also correct. You don't require to alloc data object and you can directly use dateFromString function which itself returns NSDate object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,  now it works with the following code:

```
NSString *myDate = @"06/18/2015 8:26:17 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM. HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
cell.timeLabel.text = dateString;
```